# A PHP Error was encountered (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Tags: php

> Severity: Warning  Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused  Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php  Line Number: 201

Code:

```
    if ($this->_mysqli->real_connect($hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database, $port, $socket, $client_flags))
```

Comment: *Sounds* like the `$hostname` is incorrect or behind a firewall after a quick search on the error... I'm guessing it perhaps should be `$this->hostname` ? ... maybe?

Comment: Can you show us what's below `Line Number: 201`, which we are more concerned about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens **before** your username and password are checked.

Make sure your `$hostname` is correct. If your database is running locally, make sure it's also bound to an IP address, not just a socket (alternatively, set `$hostname` to the socket path).

Comment: Are you sure as an answer? Or is this more of a comment?

Comment: I will expand my answer once OP expands his question. Or even asks a question, for that matter.